# Blender 2.79b crashes on start V2

Tags: windows, installation

This question is a continuation of this: [Blender 2.79b crashes on start up](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109236/blender-2-79b-crashes-on-start-up/109979?noredirect=1#comment193958_109979)

System: Windows 10
Drivers:

```
Nvidia: **397.93** 05/24/2018 - this is the lastest driver    
Intel: I use Intel® Driver & Support Assistant to update all CPU drivers and i also have the lastest one.
```

In weekend I reinstalled Windows 10, and install Blender 2.79b.
When i double click on the blender icon, the Console starts first, then i get the gray Blender window and it's immediately closes.

Here is my log file, when i run `"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe" --debug-memory --debug-gpumem --debug-all > results.txt.` in **CMD**:

```
AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead
SRNA Subclassed: 'Context'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'PropertyGroup'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Bone'
SRNA Subclassed: 'EditBone'
SRNA Subclassed: 'PoseBone'
SRNA Subclassed: 'UIList'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Mesh'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Object'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Texture'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Header'
SRNA Subclassed: 'KeyingSetInfo'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Node'
SRNA Subclassed: 'NodeInternal'
SRNA Subclassed: 'ShaderNode'
SRNA Subclassed: 'CompositorNode'
SRNA Subclassed: 'TextureNode'
SRNA Subclassed: 'WindowManager'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'RenderEngine'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'PropertyGroup'
SRNA Subclassed: 'AddonPreferences'
I0603 15:00:57.028302  7828 blender_python.cpp:186] Debug flags initialized to:
CPU flags:
  AVX2   : True
  AVX    : True
  SSE4.1 : True
  SSE3   : True
  SSE2   : True
  QBVH   : True
  Split  : False
CUDA flags:
 Adaptive Compile: False
OpenCL flags:
  Device type    : ALL
  Kernel type    : DEFAULT
  Debug          : False
  Single program : True
  Memory limit   : zu
I0603 15:00:57.049250  7828 device_opencl.cpp:59] CLEW initialization succeeded.
Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
```

Comment: Which GPU are you using/CPU? It might not be supported. Also, that setting hertz error makes me think there is something wrong with your system settings. Perhaps reset the BIOS to default values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a solution. This is all because of **Intel HD Graphics dirver**, which works together with my Nvidia Geforce graphic card.

Step to solve:

a. Press Windows Key + X, choose Device Manager.

b. Expand the Display Adapters.

C. Right-click on the **Intel HD Graphics** graphics card driver and click on Uninstall.

Then i start blender and all works fine!
But what happen with Intel craphic driver, i don't know)