# Just installed for the first time. Blender closes instantly upon starting up

Tags: gpu, windows

I apologize if this is a common issue, but I cannot for the life of me understand how to startup the program. I just finished installing for the first time, yet Blender will not even run. I had to do a fast 'print screen' capture of what happens when I execute "Blender.exe". The command prompt will briefly flash with the message "found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\python", and the main screen will appear before disappearing and closing altogether less than half a second later.

[image: command prompt before sudden closing]

So far I have done a clean install of Blender, repaired it, made sure I had Microsoft C++ package 2013 installed, updated my drivers, and even reinstalled python. Nothing has worked. Is there any solution to starting it up for me without it suddenly crashing/closing immediately afterwards?

As for PC specs, I use Windows 10 Operating system, and my G-card is an Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080. I have an i7 intel processor and 16 GB of Ram installed. Please let me know if you need any more information!

Comment: Try the [zipped version](https://www.blender.org/download/Blender2.79/blender-2.79b-windows64.zip).

Comment: Similar issue? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110039/blender-2-79b-crashes-on-start-v2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

I have had a problem similar to yours when I first started out with Blender.

Firstly, I would recommend first running a debug on the program to identify what exactly could be the error. You can do this from the Command Prompt on a Windows machine. To do this, open up the Prompt (Win+R, type 'cmd' and then hit enter) and you'll want to navigate to where your Blender executable file is located. The easy way is to right-click on the Blender shortcut on your desktop (if you set for one to appear at installation), select 'Properties', and the copy the Target folder, then return to the Command Prompt and type 'cd' and paste the destination folder (cd C:/…/Blender).

Once that's done, simply type 'blender --debug'. Blender should run now, and if it instantly closes you'll now be able to see why.

What helped me when I had that problem was that I checked with two different programs to see if my drivers were updated. I know you said you have already updated them all, but there are some outdated drivers that one piece of software will not pick up, or it is not in the program's list of drivers to check (i.e. Intel driver checkers seem to only check Intel drivers and not exactly all of them), so it might be a good idea to look for a reliable software to check your drivers with. I use DriverEasy combined with the Intel Driver and Support Assistant to make sure *all* of my drivers can get updates, even ones outside of the ones IDSA looks at. We often thing our drivers are updated, but there's always some that are missed that are crucial to some program function.

Hope it helped! Good luck and happy Blending!

Answer (score 0):

Try to start Blender via PowerShell. Go to *C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender*, then **Shift + Right Mouse Click** over a blank area and choose *Open PowerShell window here*. Type `./blender -d` and press *Enter*. It's like running Blender with double-click over the icon, but the PowerShell window should keep opened also if Blender quits. In this way, you could see if there is any error and, if yes, at least what kind of error is.